# How may I create a C++(/CX ?) _DESKTOP_ Windows 8 application using XAML for GUI?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, c++-cx

how may I create a C++ (maybe requiring /CX extension) **desktop** Windows 8 application using XAML (and its visual editor) for the GUI?
To be explicit NOT creating a Windows store application, I mean, something similar to using plain C++ and Qt (with Designer).

Comment: That's not possible.  Maybe some day, not now.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Desktop and Windows App Store are essentially incompatible target environments.  There is no desktop XAML (i.e. WPF) project type for C++.

Your options are:

1. use WinForms to create a C++/CLI desktop app with a designer
2. use MFC to create a native C++ desktop app with a designer
3. use native Win32 calls to create a native C++ desktop app *without* a designer