# Any way to use XAML and WPF from native C++ application on Windows x, where x < 8?

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, mfc, c++-cx

So we've got a legacy application that uses MFC and win32 resources to specify the user interface elements. In looking at C++/CX and WRL, I see a number of possibilities. However, we're not interested presently in the Windows Store or the Modern UI.We need to support Windows 7 for a good while yet, and we'll probably always want to be a desktop application. Is there a migration path away from MFC and resource files to an XML-based UI specification that allows us to keep writing native C++ (at least for 90% of the existing code base) but doesn't require Windows 8 or restrict us to the Metro sandbox?

Comment: If not, is there a way to use something XAML-ish to specify MFC UI layouts?

Comment: XAML works with C++, for WPF you need to use C++/CLI -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776355/does-wpf-work-with-c

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That approach looks like I'd need C++/CLI, which means we'd be writing at least some managed code, though. As I understand it, we'd pay for a managed to native transition on each button click or other UI message, so presumably there would be a performance hit there. The reason I mention CX and WRL is that it allows a fully native code base.

Comment: @Jay Depends on how you do the managed to un-managed interface. If you have to marshal tons of data it could take a long time. But in general, if you do a good job of separating your implementation from your GUI, than you shouldn't have to cross that barrier all to often. Remember, people respond to GUI slow down on the order of tens of milliseconds. C++/CLI uses the "IJW" approach to merge native and managed code fairly efficiently. But C++/CLI is NOT C++, so if you don't want to learn another language go with something else.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, So C++/CX has WRL to do things in a more COM/ATL-like way, with HRESULTs instead of exceptions. Analogously, is there a way to use .NET interop instead of CLI to bridge that gap? I'm trying to think whether that might be a better fit.

What I'm wondering is, what is it that enabled a purely native solution for the Windows Store/Windows Runtime in Win8 if that's not possible to do in Windows 7? It seems like Microsoft skipped a natural step in the evolution somewhere.

Comment: In other words, if some part of WPF & XAML requires managed code, how did they get around that requirement for Windows Store apps on the Windows Runtime? I guess the Win RT encapsulates the managed bits somehow... It sounds like my question might be largely a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434433/how-may-i-create-a-c-cx-desktop-windows-8-application-using-xaml-for-gui?rq=1

Comment: @Jay it's important to mention that the XAML implementation in WinRT is NOT WPF. It's more like a re-make of WPF. In fact, there are several XAML-level and framework-level features that you find in WPF that are absent in WinRT. The WinRT XAML feature set is really closed to Silverlight in that sense, but the inner workings of it are different, because it's not .Net.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks. That's yet another reason WinRT is sounding like a non-starter for this project. If that's a prerequisite for C++/CX or WRL, then it sounds like the overall answer to this question is "No, you can't write native C++ code for Windows 8 Desktop and Windows 7 and earlier and take advantages of WPF, XAML, or partial classes."

Comment: @Jay well, WPF is part of .Net, and .Net is managed. No way around that. There's recent news about Microsoft working on ".Net Native" but it is unclear whether that will be available for Desktop .Net. At the moment they're talking about doing it precisely for mobile platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF isn't bound to Windows 8. It's available from Vista on. There are different ways to integrate WPF in an existing MFC application, depending on your application design. You could use ActiveX with .NET interoperability -- or you could implement a client-server architecture using XMLRPC with your program logic residing in the server and interface design in the WPF frontend.